# .click event doesn't seem to fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I've got the following code inside of a `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toolbarReset").click(function() {
    alert("I've been clicked! Oh, what a world!");
  });

  ... other, unrelated functions, which all seem to work fine    

});
```

... and some html below:

```
<span id="toolbarReset" style="line-height: 18px; width: 50px; height: 21px; padding: 0pt 7px 0pt 3px;">
  Reset
</span>
```

... but when I click on the words "Reset", nothing happens.

Tried changing it from using "id" to "class", and updating the jQuery code appropriately ( *"#toolbarReset"* became *"toobarReset"* ). Tried putting some code inside the .click event to output to the Firebug console, and verified that "toolbarReset" is a unique id within the DOM.

Comment: If you remove all of your other script, does it work? Is your span dynamically added to the DOM? I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: did you check that the ready function it's actually running?

Comment: perhaps try validating your html as well to see if there are any errors

Comment: Using firebug, do any javascript errors get logged (not something that you tried to write to the console from within your click event). It seems that your click event isn't firing at all so any code in there won't work. Is your span dynamically created? Have you tried the JSFiddle examples below, and do they work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a timing issue. My jQuery code was running before the  element was loaded on the page, due to where I placed them in relation to one another - hence the jQuery was trying to bind to an ID that didn't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me, what browser are you using?

http://jsfiddle.net/YLCff/

Comment: I would suggest validating your page through W3C to see if there are stray tags causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have more than one #toolbarReset, if this is the case it will not work until you remove other ids.

Comment: Thought of that. Did a "View source" for my live page, and confirmed that the only two places "toolbarReset" appear are (1) in the jQuery code, and (2) in the span tag

Comment: check if you embedded all needed jquery files 'alerts, it's strange because the code is working for me! try the jAlert(message, [title, callback])

Comment: #toolbarReset represents the id of an html element.  HTML spec dictates that ids are unique.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score -1):

I checked the code in my browser it worked . Anyway try using .on instead of .click.

i.e

```
 $("#toolbarReset").on('click',function() {
// watever code
}
```

Comment: The .click method and .on method with parameter for event 'click' are absolutely identical. Please avoid answering to questions which are very old and already have their accpeted answer unless you have some new or helpflul/completing information.